# JQuery filter on children's class after .get()

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

**Problem**: I want to do a *.get()* but only with the elements without the *.played* class. (I'm building a shuffle playlist, played numbers are being marked by a *.played* class on their div).

**Current code**:

```
var randomElements = $("#playlistVideos").get();
```

**What I tried:** the filter() and a lot of selector tricks, none of them succeed. I'm very interested in how you will solve a problem like this!

**HTML**:

```
<div id="playlistVideos">
<div class="vt ddsitem">
    <a href="javascript:loadAndPlayVideo('wQ5iFQv1KaE')"><img class="pt" id="wQ5iFQv1KaE" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/wQ5iFQv1KaE/default.jpg"></a>
    <div>
        <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px; position: relative; left: 100px; bottom: 98px;" class="updown" src="images/updown.gif"><a style="cursor: pointer;" href="javascript:deleteVideo('wQ5iFQv1KaE')"><img style="width: 18px; height: 18px; position: relative; left: 150px; bottom: 98px; cursor: pointer;" class="bin" src="images/bin.gif"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="vt ddsitem">
    <a href="javascript:loadAndPlayVideo('Ya3_wQpzDIU')"><img class="pt" id="Ya3_wQpzDIU" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ya3_wQpzDIU/default.jpg"></a>
    <div>
        <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px; position: relative; left: 100px; bottom: 98px;" class="updown" src="images/updown.gif"><a style="cursor: pointer;" href="javascript:deleteVideo('Ya3_wQpzDIU')"><img style="width: 18px; height: 18px; position: relative; left: 150px; bottom: 98px; cursor: pointer;" class="bin" src="images/bin.gif"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="vt ddsitem played">
    <a href="javascript:loadAndPlayVideo('Dq0hrmT7JiQ')"><img class="pt" id="Dq0hrmT7JiQ" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Dq0hrmT7JiQ/default.jpg"></a>
    <div>
        <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px; position: relative; left: 100px; bottom: 98px;" class="updown" src="images/updown.gif"><a style="cursor: pointer;" href="javascript:deleteVideo('Dq0hrmT7JiQ')"><img style="width: 18px; height: 18px; position: relative; left: 150px; bottom: 98px; cursor: pointer;" class="bin" src="images/bin.gif"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="vt ddsitem">
    <a href="javascript:loadAndPlayVideo('WklNzfvit9E')"><img class="pt" id="WklNzfvit9E" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/WklNzfvit9E/default.jpg"></a>
    <div>
        <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px; position: relative; left: 100px; bottom: 98px;" class="updown" src="images/updown.gif"><a style="cursor: pointer;" href="javascript:deleteVideo('WklNzfvit9E')"><img style="width: 18px; height: 18px; position: relative; left: 150px; bottom: 98px; cursor: pointer;" class="bin" src="images/bin.gif"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can use the [*:not()*](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.  You can also use the [*.not()*](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method which works in a similar way to *.filter()* except that it narrows down to elements that don't match the selector.

```
// Using :not()
var randomElements = $('#playlistVideos .vt:not(.played)').get();

// Using .not()
var randomElements = $('#playlistVideos .vt').not('.played').get();
```

Here is an example from jQuery.com for *.not()*: http://jsfiddle.net/JVNVL/.

Comment: Thnx Andy E for your reaction!

Comment: @MeProtozoan: no problem.  BTW, I really liked your format for the question, so I up voted it earlier. It's rare to see a relatively new user put that kind of effort in.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("#playlistVideos .vt:not(.played)").get()
```

should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$('#playlistVideos .vt:not(.played)')
```